# Tengo que ingresar numeros enteros y cuando se ingrese un numero primo el programa debe detenerse. Python

Tags: python

El problema esta en que no puedo salir del bucle while, supuestamente la función para detectar el numero primo devuelve un valor False lo que en teoría debería permitir que el bucle terminase pero ese no es el caso.
Codigo:

```
b = True

def es_primo(num):

    for n in range(2, num):
        if num % n == 0:
            print("No es primo", n, "es divisor")
            return True
    print("Es primo")
    return False

def ingresar():

    while b:
        a = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero: "))
        es_primo(a)
ingresar()
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que `b` nunca cambia. La solución es

```
    b = es_primo(a)
```

Además tienes que mover la inicialización de `b` dentro de la función, ya que necesitas que `b` sea `True` cada vez que la llamas.

```
<h3>Demo</h3>


def es_primo(num):

    for n in range(2, num):
        if num % n == 0:
            print("No es primo", n, "es divisor")
            return True
    print("Es primo")
    return False

def ingresar():
    b = True
    while b:
        a = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero: "))
        b = es_primo(a)
        
ingresar()
```

produce:

```
Ingrese un numero entero: 6
No es primo 2 es divisor
Ingrese un numero entero: 4
No es primo 2 es divisor
Ingrese un numero entero: 3
Es primo

Process finished with exit code 0
```